# single li top border on hover without rest of the list

Tags: css, menu, hover

live link here
http://soloveich.com/pr1-1/

Trying put a border (and later arrow in the middle) on hover in menu.
But with this code, it puts a border over entire menu, and individual li on top of that.

```
#menu ul li {
margin-top: -50px;
padding-top: 50px;
float: right;
margin-right: 30px;
display: inline-block;
}
#menu li:hover {
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-color: red;
border-top-width: 3px;
}
```

a:hover does the trick, but i couldn't figure out a way to put the border way on top, and I'm expecting problem putting the arrow caret there, as well

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
.menu-menu-1-container li:hover {
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-color: red;
border-top-width: 3px;
}
```

Or:

```
#menu li li:hover {
border-top-style: solid;
border-top-color: red;
border-top-width: 3px;
}
```